# how to get max area of k-gon?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, algol

I am trying to get the max area of quad embedded in convex hull.
I use the way from paper, but something was wrong. This code is `ALGOL-60`, I am not sure the loop  while and repeat means.

[image: on a general method for maximizing and minimizing among certain geometric problems]

This is my java code:

```
    private static Quad getQua(Point[] z) {
    Point A = z[0], B = z[1], C = z[2], D = z[3];
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3;
    int n = z.length;
    while (true) {
        while (true) {
            while (true) {
                while (Area(z[a], z[b], z[c], z[d]) <= Area(z[a], z[b], z[c], z[(d + 1) % n])) {
                    d = (d + 1) % n;
                }
                if (Area(z[a], z[b], z[c], z[d]) > Area(z[a], z[b], z[(c + 1) % n], z[d])) {
                    break;
                }
                c = (c + 1) % n;
            }
            if (Area(z[a], z[b], z[c], z[d]) > Area(z[a], z[(b + 1) % n], z[c], z[d])) {
                break;
            }
            b = (b + 1) % n;
        }
        if (Area(z[a], z[b], z[c], z[d]) > Area(A, B, C, D)) {
            A = z[a];B = z[b];C = z[c];D = z[d];
        }
        a = (a + 1) % n;
        if (a == b) {
            b = (b + 1) % n;
        }
        if (b == c) {
            c = (c + 1) % n;
        }
        if (c == d) {
            d = (d + 1) % n;
        }
        if (a == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Quad q=new Quad(A, B, C, D);
    L.d(q.area+"  ");
    return q;
}
```

Comment: You know, it's probably easier to understand the formula for the area of a regular polygon with n sides, and then translate that understanding into code. Trying to translate a bunch of 50-year-old code that's in a language you don't understand and that does something you don't understand is going to be very confusing. See http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_regular_polygon.htm

Comment: This code is not in Algol 60 but in pseudo-code. There is no **loop** keyword in Algol 60. That is why no one has answered; you are looking for a description of semantics that do not exist.